# Magento2 Max Depth Top Category Navigation

Tags: magento-2.1, category, topmenu

Changing the max depth in the admin section does not apply to the frontend.

Anyone has done a workaround to display just the first-level categories in the top menu?

Comment: Have you not just though about changing Show In Menu to No

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can set in the default.xml in your theme Magento_Theme folder:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="columns_limit" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

With this, you can determine the depth of the menu. Magento will still render the `<ul></ul>` but with some styling, you can remove this.

still not the most beautiful solution, but will be fixed in future Magento releases.

Answer (score -1):

Not a solution but will be fixed in Magento 2.3.X 
As you can see here:

    [https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7543][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7543